# How do i write the following statements in XAML for RelativeLayout of Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to arrange some controls inside a RelativeLayout of Xamarin Forms.
In C#, i wrote the following code to archive my goal:

```
_avatar = new Xamarin.Forms.Image();
_rlTopLayout.Children.Add(_avatar, 
    xConstraint: Constraint.Constant(0),
    yConstraint: Constraint.Constant(0),
    widthConstraint: Constraint.Constant(78),
    heightConstraint: Constraint.Constant(94)
);
_roundedBorderEntry = new Xamarin.Forms.Entry();
_rlTopLayout.Children.Add(_roundedBorderEntry,
    xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(_avatar, (parent, sibling) => sibling.X + sibling.Width),
    yConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(_avatar, (parent, sibling) => sibling.Y),
    widthConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(_avatar, (parent, sibling) => parent.Width - sibling.Width),
    heightConstraint: null
);
```

How do i archive this with XAML layout file? Especially with the following expression:

```
xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(_avatar, (parent, sibling) => sibling.X + sibling.Width)
widthConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(_avatar, (parent, sibling) => parent.Width - sibling.Width)
heightConstraint: null
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating `RelativeLayout` constraints is surely easier in code than in XAML. You can see [this thread on Xamarin.Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17742/relativelayout-in-xaml) where developers discuss the available syntax.

For your case it however might not be enough. See the post by **MikeEEE** who created a custom markup extension to handle the special cases. He published example on his GitHub [here](https://github.com/Michael-DST/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/Support/RelativeToViewHorizontal.cs), [here](https://github.com/Michael-DST/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/Support/RelativeToViewVertical.cs) and sample page [here](https://github.com/Michael-DST/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/RelativeLayoutDemoPage.xaml).

Answer (score 1):

XAML, assuming the image is 100 by 50:

```
<RelativeLayout x:Name="relativeLayout" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
  <Image x:Name="image" Source="100x50.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="50"/>
  <Entry x:Name="entry" Text="enter text here"
         RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=image, 
                                    Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=-100}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note that in XAML `sibling` refer to a named element using `x:Name` and the `ElementName=elementName` construct.